# How do I permanently change the values of a text file?

Tags: python

im fairly new to handling files so im just confused

```
#pretend this is a text file, do not modify this part of the code.....
emps='''20120001;Tortor;Griffin;Manager;Admin;1000;5000
20120002;Sebastian;Jest;Assist. Manager;Admin;750;3000'''

f = open('empList.txt','w')
f.write(emps)
f.close()

#Code here
employees = []
while True:
    print('''1 - Show Employees
2 - Increase Salary to employees
X - Exit
    ''')
    choice = input('Enter your choice: ')
    print()
    if choice =='2':
        with open('empList.txt', 'r') as f:
            employees = f.read().splitlines()
        for employee in employees:
            emp_num, last, first, position, dept, salary, allowance = employee.split(';')
            if position == 'Manager':
                print(f'{emp_num} {last} {first} {float(salary)*2} {dept} {allowance} {position}')
            else:
                print(f'{emp_num} {last} {first} {float(salary)*1.5} {dept} {allowance} {position}')
        print()
    elif choice =='1':
        with open('empList.txt', 'r') as f:
            employees = f.read().splitlines()
        for employee in employees:
            emp_num, last, first, position, dept, salary, allowance = employee.split(';')
            print(f'{emp_num} {last} {first} {float(salary)} {dept} {allowance} {position}')
        print()
    elif choice =='X':
        break
```

my problem is whenever I input Choice 2 the changed values for salary is not permanent, so whenever I change the values by inputting Choice 2, it still shows the unchanged values, how do I fix this?

probably because I'm using a print statement but I'm in a stump as to what function I'm supposed to use here, I thought of using append but it would just make a copy of the data, what am I missing?

so something like this is the problem.

```
1 - Show Employees
2 - Increase Salary to employees
X - Exit
    
Enter your choice: 2

20120001 Tortor Griffin 2000.0 Admin 5000 Manager
20120002 Sebastian Jest 1125.0 Admin 3000 Assist. Manager

1 - Show Employees
2 - Increase Salary to employees
X - Exit
    
Enter your choice: 1

20120001 Tortor Griffin 1000.0 Admin 5000 Manager <---Value didn't change to 2000.0?
20120002 Sebastian Jest 750.0 Admin 3000 Assist. Manager <---Value didn't change to 1125.0?

1 - Show Employees
2 - Increase Salary to employees
X - Exit
```

Comment: At what point in the code are you changing the values?

Comment: @matszwecja At choice 2, in which the value of "salary" will be changed to * 2 of its original value, or just *1.5 if the position is not "Manager".

Comment: No, that's just outputting `salary*2` to console. You never actually modify any data.

Comment: yeah and that's my problem, I have no clue how I'm supposed to modify my data here, I only print them out

Comment: I Think it will be better to create a pandas DataFrame with the values in the file and store the final result when the user exits the progam. So in every iteration you just need to modify the correspondant value in the DataFrame. Just check out the pandas documentation for pandas.read_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html and for pandas to_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are opening the file with `'r'`, which is in read-only mode. You need to change it to `'w'`, like: `with open('empList.txt', 'w')`.

Second thing is you are not writing anything to the file, you are just printing it. You miss `f.write(...)` in the choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the new data and then write it back to the file using write() function something like below. Note that the code is not tested but the approach should help you figure out the solution.

```
if choice =='2':
    with open('empList.txt', 'r') as f:
        employees = f.read().splitlines()
    # create a new list to store modified employee data
    modified_employees = []
    for employee in employees:
        emp_num, last, first, position, dept, salary, allowance = employee.split(';')
        if position == 'Manager':
            # Append current employee record with modified salary to the new list
            modified_employees.append("{};{};{};{};{};{};{}".format(emp_num, last, first, position, dept, salary*2, allowance))
            print(f'{emp_num} {last} {first} {float(salary)*2} {dept} {allowance} {position}')
        else:
            # Append current employee record with modified salary to the new list
            modified_employees.append("{};{};{};{};{};{};{}".format(emp_num, last, first, position, dept, salary*1.5, allowance))
            print(f'{emp_num} {last} {first} {float(salary)*1.5} {dept} {allowance} {position}')
    # Write the new list back to file. This will overwrite previous content and keeps the fresh
    with open('empList.txt', 'w') as f:
        for each_record in modified_employees:
            f.write("{}\n".format(each_record))
```